# objective c - significant location changes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm building a client-server app, and I need that the server will always know what is the current client location.
So when the client app is active I use `CLLocationManager` to get the client location every 10 minutes and send it to the server.
My problem is what to do when the app is close?  I know I can use significant location changes to get location updates when the app is close, but can I send this location updates to my server without launching the app? I mean when the app is close I want it to be transparent to the user, Is this possible? Does something happen with the UI when I get one of this location updates?

Comment: If user has closed the app, that means he does not want to publish his location to the server. But yes, if its in background than you can send the info to server.

Comment: as far as I know significant location change notifications work event if the app is close...

Comment: yea what you said is correct, I missed that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html), they say

> the system automatically relaunches the application into the
>   background if a new event arrives, In such a case, the options dictionary passed to the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method of your application delegate contains the key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey to indicate that your application was launched because of a location event.
>
> Upon relaunch, you must still configure a location manager object and
>   call this method to continue receiving location events. When you
>   restart location services, the current event is delivered to your
>   delegate immediately. In addition, the location property of your
>   location manager object is populated with the most recent location
>   object even before you start location services

You can send the location to server without showing any UI element.

Answer (score 1):

Your app will be listed in the settings area as well as displaying the location indicator icon and you can receive and process (send to the server) those updates as they occur. Check out this tutorial: http://www.mindsizzlers.com/2011/07/ios-background-location/